# read XML file from one server to another server on the same network

Tags: c#, xml, impersonation, file-copying

I have hosted my application on a server having IP 12.3.4.56 and my datastore reside on another server having IP 12.3.4.57 in same network.

I want to read XML file from my datastore server to application server.
When I fire "\\12.3.4.57\ABC\DEF\" in run prompt it opens the correct folder on both server. I have given everyone read/write shared access on folder also.

When I try to read file from my application server using below code it throws an error.

```
string XMLFilePath = "\\12.3.4.57\ABC\DEF\dir.xml";
XmlDocument DirDoc = new XmlDocument();
DirDoc.Load(XMLFilePath);
```

Error: The username or password is incorrect.

The same error occurred when I try to copy file from my datastore server to application server using below code.

```
string sourceFile = "\\12.3.4.57\ABD\DEF\Test123 (26).pdf";
string Folder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/SavedPDFs");
string destPDFFile = string.Concat(Folder, "Test123 (26).pdf");
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destPDFFile, true);
```

Comment: This sounds like a file security question, not a programming question.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me here. What should I do here to resolve it? Is It not belongs to impersonate issue?

Comment: The user who runs these codes must be a user of the destination machine.

Comment: It sounds like you need to configure the network and file share permissions correctly.  You can remove all the code, leaving just the file share information and ask it on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Is this a Webapplication in IIS? What useraccount is running the Web site?(Application pool)

Comment: Yes, webapplication hosted on IIS 10 with Application Pool - .NET CLR v4.0.30319

Comment: And under what identity is the Application Pool running?

Comment: "ApplicationPoolIdentity"

Comment: Try changing to Network Service account or a domain account (try with your own and verify if it works)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are forgetting to escape the backslash causing the "permission" problem.

Your code should look like this

```
string XMLFilePath = @"\\12.3.4.57\ABC\DEF\dir.xml"; // note the leading @ sign
XmlDocument DirDoc = new XmlDocument();
DirDoc.Load(XMLFilePath);


string sourceFile = @"\\12.3.4.57\ABD\DEF\Test123 (26).pdf";  // note the leading @ sign
string Folder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/SavedPDFs");
string destPDFFile = string.Concat(Folder, "Test123 (26).pdf"); // I assume that the Folder variable will have the frontslash at the end
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destPDFFile, true);
```